# Java help 61 errors that I don't understand

Tags: java

I am reading this book on Java and in the first chapter the book says to copy this code into a text editor.  So I type it all out, compile it and the compiler tells me I have 61 errors.

Obviously since this is in the first chapter I don't know all of the specifics of Java so these errors are completely beyond me.  I'm not sure how an example could have so many errors unless I am doing something wrong which is very likely.

Here is the code:

```
class VolcanoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        VocanoRobot dante = new VolcanoRobot();
        dante.status = "exploring";
        dante.speed = 2;
        dante.tempurature = 510;

        dante.showAttributes();
        System.out.println("Increasing speed to 3.");
        dante.spped = 3;
        dante.showAttributes();
        System.out.println("Changing temperature to 670.");
        dante.temperature = 670;
        dante.showAttributes();
        System.out.println("Checking temperature.");
        dante.checkTemperature();
        dante.showAttributes();
    }
}
```

Most of the errors consist of "expected ';'". I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: first of all, when you increase speed to 3, you call dante.spped, which would also cause a compile error. I can suppose that's the source of it

Comment: You have few spelling mistakes. Fix that and some of the errors will go away.

Comment: Start with the first error. Often when the compiler hits an error it gets confused and generates a slew of additional errors. Fix the first error, then recompile and you'll probably see a number of them go away. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Is this code copy&pasted exactly as the code you tried to compile? You have spelled `VolcanoRobot` wrong the first time you use the name. Plus some more spelling mistakes.

Comment: Fix your spelling mistakes as John and Roger have pointed out. If it still doesn't compile, edit your question with the stack trace that shows the errors.

Comment: is that *all* the code there is? No imports, no other files?

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Everything worked fine after fixing the spelling errors. I appreciate the help.  I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spelt Volcano wrong in:

```
VocanoRobot dante = new VolcanoRobot();
```

It should probably be (Forgot an 'l' in the first Volcano):

```
VolcanoRobot dante = new VolcanoRobot();
```

Try that and see if you have any other errors.